# While debugging protractor UI tests in Visual Studio Code breakpoints are not hit

Tags: debugging, protractor, visual-studio-code

I have an Angular 2+ project with Protractor UI tests with a layer of CucumberJS over it, thus I can define steps in Gherkin.

In Visual Studio Code I have defined launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/protractor.conf.js"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "./dist/out-tsc"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "compounds": []
}
```

When I press F5 all the tests are executed and they all success, however no breakpoint is hit. **On the other hand there is no problem with hitting breakpoints in WebStorm, I just point to the protractor.conf and it works**.

Question: What more should I declare in launch.json to enable hitting the breakpoints in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Your launch.json seems correct, I think it is the tsconfig.json that may be wrong.

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ],
    "lib":[
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}